# prisma: How to convert a database table with more that one FK to prisma schema?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, prisma

I'm new to Prisma and relational databases in general. I'm a little bit confused about how to create many-to-many relations between tables, especially relation fields.

For example, imagine I want to convert this database model to Prisma schema.
[image]

This is the answare that I came up with:

```
model User {
  id             String         @id
  comments       Comment[]
  posts          Post[]
}

model Post {
  id             Int            @default(autoincrement()) @id
  author         User           @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId       String
  comments       Comment[]
}

model Comment {
  id             Int            @default(autoincrement()) @id
  post           Post           @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  postId         Int       
  author         User           @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId       String
  text           String
}
```

The `Comment` table has two foreign keys to both `User` and `Post` tables. Do I need to have the `comments` field in both models? And in general, Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the database model you posted, your Prisma Schema seems perfectly fine. Let me go relation by relation.

#### One-to-many relation between User and Post

This is perfectly fine. The Post table should hold a foreign key for the `User.id` field.

#### Many-to-many relation between User and Post (via the Comment relation table).

This is again, perfectly fine. You are also correct that the `comments` field needs to be in both models.

##### Some notes on explicit vs implicit many-to-many relations

In Prisma terminology, the way you have explicitly defined the many-to-many `Comment` table is called an **explicit** many-to-many relation. Since the `Comment` table has a separate `text` field, it makes sense to use an explicit many-to-many relation.

If the `text` field did not exist, you could have used an **implicit** many-to-many relation. You can optionally read up more on this in the Many-to-many relations section of the [Relations Concept Article](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#implicit-vs-explicit-many-to-many-relations) in the prisma docs.

*As a side note*, your diagram seems to have the `authorId` foreign-key incorrectly listed as an `INT` type. I beleive this should be `TEXT`.

Comment: Thank you, sir. You answered all of my questions. And about authorId data type, you are right, it should be TEXT.

Comment: Happy to help :D. As a side note, if you need help or suggestions with Prisma, we have a very active community on [Slack](https://slack.prisma.io/). Feel free to join if you'd like!